# Bisecting K-Means spark ml - what is the division rule?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I started using Bisecting K-Means Clustering in pyspark and I am wondering what is the division rule during clustering.

I know that K-Means is done there, but how next cluster for next division is selected? I have seen that there are couple of methods ( eg. biggest cluster is divided / cluster with less internal similarity), but I can't find what is division rule implemented in spark ml.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Pyspark ML documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.clustering.BisectingKMeans), Bisecting KMeans algorithm is based on the paper “A comparison of document clustering techniques” by Steinbach, Karypis, and Kumar (https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dunja/KDDpapers/Steinbach_IR.pdf).

In section 3:

> We found little difference between the possible methods for  selecting
>   a  cluster  to  split  and  chose  to  split  the  largest  remaining
>   cluster.

Modifications were made for Pyspark. According to the Pyspark doc :

> The algorithm starts from a single cluster that contains all points.
>   Iteratively it finds divisible clusters on the bottom level and
>   bisects each of them using k-means, until there are k leaf clusters in
>   total or no leaf clusters are divisible. The bisecting steps of
>   clusters on the same level are grouped together to increase
>   parallelism. If bisecting all divisible clusters on the bottom level
>   would result more than k leaf clusters, larger clusters get higher
>   priority.

Comment: Wonder what would make a leaf cluster indivisible